# How to access Rails 5.2 credentials with Cloud9 C9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c9.io

I need help with how to access and edit my Rails 5.2 credentials.yml.enc file using Cloud9.

I’ve tried several different commands using the EDITOR=“something --wait” format, but each time I enter rails credentials:edit, I just get this error: “No $EDITOR to open file in.”

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use from your terminal

EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit

The config/credentials.yml.enc file opens in your terminal with vim.
To edit it with vim:
- move with the arrows
- When you want to insert text press "i" when done press "ESC"
- To save use ":w"
- To exit use ":q"